# Readfile operation completes but fills data buffer with multiple messages / Serial communication

Tags: c++, serial-port, readfile

I'm working on a application that reads data on a serial port. Various messages can be sent over this serial port in a short period of time, and the thread that reads incoming data must identify what type of message it reads when the ReadFile operation completes. I'm using an overlapped structure and I want messages to be read one by one.

My problem is that the ReadFile operation often fills the buffer with multiple messages and I can't find values of com timeouts that prevent this from hapening. I suspect that reading operation doesn't complete when two messages are received back to back, which is seen from the reading thread as a single message as there is still data on the serial port when the first message is complete.

I'm observing the same phenomenon using a non-overlapped structure.

I'm using a serial com, configured as followed:

```
    DCB configPort = { 0 };
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;

    this->hDevice = CreateFileA(
            this->portReady,
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            OPEN_EXISTING,
            FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
            NULL
    );

    if (this->hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cout << "INVALID HANDLE" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    OvReception.Offset = 0;
    OvReception.OffsetHigh = 0;
    OvReception.hEvent = ::CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, _T("")); 

    configPort.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);
    configPort.BaudRate = CBR_38400;
    configPort.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    configPort.Parity = EVENPARITY;
    configPort.ByteSize = 8;
    configPort.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE;

    configPort.fAbortOnError = 0;
    configPort.XonLim = 800;
    configPort.XoffLim = 2000;

    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 1;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;

    if (!SetCommState(this->hDevice, &configPort)) {
        CloseHandle(this->hDevice);
        return 0;
    }

    if (!SetCommTimeouts(this->hDevice, &timeouts)) {
        CloseHandle(this->hDevice);
        return 0;
    }
```

And I read incoming data using :

```
    bool readState = false;
    char incomingMessage[512] = {0};
    DWORD bytesRead = 0;
    memset(incomingMessage, 0, sizeof(incomingMessage));
    while (this->threadRunning) {

        readState = ReadFile(
            this->comSerie.hDevice,
            incomingMessage,
            sizeof(incomingMessage),
            NULL,
            &this->comSerie.OvReception);

        if (::GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
        {
            ::GetOverlappedResult(this->comSerie.hDevice, &this->comSerie.OvReception, &bytesRead, TRUE);
        }
        //NO ERRORS OBSERVED
        std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
        std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Message received" << std::endl;
        std::cout << incomingMessage<< std::endl;
        switch(ReceivedMessageType(incomingMessage)){
         //............ DO SOMETHING
        }
        //Clean buffer
        memset(incomingMessage, 0, sizeof(incomingMessage));
    }
```

I configured the bwait parameter to TRUE in the GetOverlappedResult so that it doesn't return before the write operation is completed.
I do not observe any error return by GetLastError().

I've also tried using WaitForSingleObject function, the issue was the same.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for the help

Comment: It's a serial medium, not a message medium. If you want messaging you have to implement it yourself, with message terminators, or length-word prefixes, or self-describing protocols like XML.

Comment: Or fixed-length messages where you only read for the fixed length.

Comment: And I don't see what `WaitForSingleObject ()` could possibly have to do with it. You can't seriously imagine that Windows knows where your messages start and stop, surely?